# Menu bar and all table name changed to unknown language in phpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Database name, right menu bar and all table name change into unknown language or symbols in phpmyadmin for original and pamahomme theme. But when i change into Metro theme everything is fine.

how to solve that error. What problem is that. I am sure i have done anything wrong.

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot and also paste the text of some section here?

Comment: Also I would suggest clearing your browser cache, using private mode, or trying a different browser entirely to test if there's some old cached data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache or use new incognito window of browser.It'd helped me to solve this problem.